# How can you safely practice strikes aimed towards the neck with a partner

Tags: kicking, safety, training, protective-equipment

For most strikes, it's easy to practice safely with a partner. Usually your training partner would just wear padding and a safety helmet.

But with strikes to the **neck**, it's a little different.

For example, if I want to practice kicks aimed at my opponent's neck, it would be hard to do accurately if my partner is wearing all that bulky safety equipment covering up their neck.

I could use a standing bag, but that doesn't replicate the fact, that the neck is inward from the rest of the body. I expect an answer from someone who has little more experience with this than me.

How can I practice strikes towards the neck with a partner without sacrificing safety or accuracy?

Comment: Why not use a bob? You can then work on your accuracy as well as power on the neck.

Comment: @RoundHouse what do you mean by that? Can you provide an image link?

Comment: [Bob](https://www.google.com/search?q=bob+standing+bag&rlz=1C1CHBD_enCA896CA896&sxsrf=ALeKk02-xqAXBMBICCFGwXQQfBsDllbsUw:1591208565466&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjri7vqoebpAhWeGDQIHTQTBboQ_AUoAnoECA0QBA&biw=1745&bih=881#imgrc=KK-1AgaUXgTEPM) is made up of hard rubber mostly. You can practice hitting specific sports like the nose, chin, and the neck.

Comment: Also see the one by [RDX](https://www.google.com/search?q=bob+standing+bag&rlz=1C1CHBD_enCA896CA896&sxsrf=ALeKk02-xqAXBMBICCFGwXQQfBsDllbsUw:1591208565466&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjri7vqoebpAhWeGDQIHTQTBboQ_AUoAnoECA0QBA&biw=1745&bih=881#imgrc=1X-qrs-CGEipGM). A friend of mine bought a Bob and attached noodles (those long foamy things) to it as its hands. So he can go under the fake hands and work on body shots; he can bob and weave too. When he kicks the neck, he trains bringing his kick over the noodles to replicated how in real sparring we have our hands up covering our chin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Side-kicks:**

Why not use a boxing paw? In a similar way you may use it to throw a hook or high-kick.

It is enough soft from the opposite side to prevent damage to the head of your partner (especially if he is in a helmet) - and enough big to protect the head.

Of course, your target is small enough - as you want to target a neck, you may strike to the bottom of paw - but that is!

**Front-kicks:**

For front-kicks to the neck - the general approach for kicks may be applied. As all what you want is to kick into a generally small target - just try to aim and hit. The problem you specified is the distance - as long as neck is a bit inward, kick distance should obviously be a bit more longer. But..

**If your problem is in distance measuring - then try to train with a rope**. Really, that helps me - especially with roundhouse kicks (ushira-geri, if more concretely).

Rope judges you realy well. In both distance and targeting (for targeting, you may just mark rope at some height with some another, colored small rope). In fact, it is an ultimate judge (and that is cool!). When training with a bag, you may hit it only a bit, or just touch it and not really hit. But for the rope - there are only two options - you hit or you miss. So, rope prevents anybody from freebie-training.

So, general answer, I think is to improve your distance sence - and for that - **rope** is really best you may do.

Comment: Ok, but what about kicks?

Comment: Oh. Maybe I see. Do you mean "front-kicks" to the neck?

Comment: Mainly front kicks, but I can also imagine round kicks and side kicks too, and possibly even wheel kicks.

Comment: @LemmyX, understand - I'm sorry, not got it from the question.  Don't know what to do - maybe delete? It is enough another way of training, not described in my answer

Comment: But if you do not mean, I'll try to rephrase

Comment: No, go ahead and keep your answer, it's just not quite what I was looking for :)

Comment: @LemmyX, done my best, and what I described really helped me. And I hope, it may help you and all other users visiting this question)